# Restoring database from another server

Tags: sql-server

I have a backup that is from FS\SQLExpress. It was taken using the SQL Database backup tool in sql server management studio.

If I try to "restore" my database on THESTUDIO\SQLExpress with it's backup it tells me that it's for the wrong server. How can I make it accept it?

Comment: Are they both SQL 2005/2008? What's the exact error message?

Comment: Both are SQL 2008, the exact error is 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'RentalEase' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to select the "Overwrite the existing database" option in the Options page in the Restore dialog. SQL Server doesn't like restoring over a different database without barking at you!

If you're using script, it's the `WITH REPLACE` option.